# get username from NTLM auth header?

Tags: http-headers, ntlm

Is there any way to work out what a user's name is just by sniffing the NTLM header?

I have an app, that accesses a NTLM auth'd site, and so an Auth prompt opens for the user to authenticate with the site by entering their username / password.

Is there any way, just with access to the headers, to find out what the entered username is?

Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Jonsie

Answer (score 7):

sure, you can do this even with a simple JSP file... (this only works with NTLMv1, not v2, I'm still looking for that..)

So the code for the JSP is (I've tried it on Apache Tomcat 6)

```
<%@ page import="sun.misc.BASE64Encoder" %>
<%
String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
String s = "";

//no auth, request NTLM
if (auth == null) {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
        return;
}
//check what client sent
if (auth.startsWith("NTLM ")) { 
        out.println(auth);

        byte[] msg = 
           new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));
        int off = 0, length, offset;
        out.println("<br>"+msg);
        out.println("<br>"+msg[1]+" "+msg[2]+" "+msg[3]+" "+msg[4]+" "+msg[5]+" "+msg[6]+" "+msg[7]+" "+msg[8]+" "+msg[9]+" "+msg[10]+"<br>");

        if (msg[8] == 1) { 
            off = 18;

            byte z = 0;
            byte[] msg1 =
                {(byte)'N', (byte)'T', (byte)'L', (byte)'M', (byte)'S',(byte)'S', (byte)'P', 
                z,(byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z,
                (byte)40, z, z, z, (byte)1, (byte)130, z, z,
                z, (byte)2, (byte)2, (byte)2, z, z, z, z, // 
                z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z};
            // send ntlm type2 msg

            response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " 
               + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1).trim());

               return;
        } 
        else if (msg[8] == 3) { 
                off = 30;
                length = msg[off+17]*256 + msg[off+16];
                offset = msg[off+19]*256 + msg[off+8];
                s = new String(msg, offset, length);
                // print computer name // out.println(s + " ");
        } 
        else
        return;

        length = msg[off+1]*256 + msg[off];
        offset = msg[off+3]*256 + msg[off+2];
        s = new String(msg, offset, length);
        //domain//out.println(s + " ");
        length = msg[off+9]*256 + msg[off+8];
        offset = msg[off+11]*256 + msg[off+10];

        s = new String(msg, offset, length);
        out.println("Hello  <span style='position:relative; width:190;" 
            + " height:10;filter:glow(Color=#009966,Strength=1)'>");
        out.println(s + "</SPAN>");
}
%>
```

Comment: Why does msg[8] == 1 mean they are unauthorised?

Comment: since this peace here helped me a lot, I thought this question should be answered for future readers. The msg[8] is the position of the version indicator. Since NTLMv1 is not recommended and supported, we want to get NTLMv2.

Comment: couldnt edit my previous comment... This is a edit and correction of it!

Since NTLMv1 is not recommended and supported, we want to get NTLMv3 by sending a NTLMv2 answer and still requesting authentication.
For reference look at [Get username using NT Challenge](https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html)