# NTLM SSO implementation in Java

Tags: java, single-sign-on, ntlm

what are the libraries in JAVA for implementing SSO? I am running my app under tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

This SourceForge project provides a pure Java SSO servlet filter and API for NTLMv2:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmv2auth/

It's based on an NTLMv2 JCIFS extension created by the Liferay portal project.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are [affiliated with that project](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), don't forget to disclose it in your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [integrated-windows-authentication-ntlm-in-a-java-weblogic-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751157/integrated-windows-authentication-ntlm-in-a-java-weblogic-app/4752907#4752907)

Answer (score 0):

Searching Google for `NTLM single-sign on java tomcat` comes up with a few interesting results, such as a link to [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/) and [this](http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?Id=103).

Comment: Waffle is only an option if tomcat us running on windows.