# Java automating Ldap authentication in ie

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

Can anyone tell me how to connect to an LDAP server?

I need a username/password authentication to be done by LDAP integrated with IE, which I intend to do using Java. Given that I only know the IP address of the server, is it possible that way I can reach the server so that I can authenticate with it somehow automatically using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [link](http://www.renemoser.net/2008/01/ldap-authentication-using-java/) to LDAP Authentication using Java

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do SSO with NTLM? In this case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751157/integrated-windows-authentication-ntlm-in-a-java-weblogic-app/4752907#4752907) might help you. Otherwise you can use the `javax.naming` package to connect to LDAP. Or have a look at [jldap](http://www.openldap.org/jldap/)